# Rolling update of kafka consumers from v0.8.2 -> 0.10.2

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

We have v0.8.2 consumers that we are in the process of updating to v0.10.2.  These are high volume applications so we normally do rolling updates.  The problem is that the v8 consumers commit offsets to zookeeper while v10 consumers commit to kafka.  In our testing, trying to run a mix of v8 and v10 consumers results in messages being double consumed.  See a more detailed writeup of the problem here: http://www.search-hadoop.com/m/Kafka/uyzND1ymwxk17UWdj?subj=Re+kafka+0+10+offset+storage+on+zookeeper

Has anyone found a work around so that we can update from v8 to v10 consumers without taking an outage?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two things here that I would suggest.

1. Do the version upgrade and the API upgrade in separate steps. You can rolling upgrade to 0.10 and continue using the old consumer API and committing offsets to zookeeper. Then in a second step do your API update. This will reduce your number of moving parts per step.
2. When doing the API update, you'll have to do some kind of full switchover because as you've observed, the consumer group info and offsets are going to be stored in Kafka now. One thing you can do to help this is here
   https://kafka.apache.org/documentation/#offsetmigration

However, the consumer groups are being coordinated differently (in the old version they are being coordinated in Zookeeper no matter where you commit offsets), so at some point you will need to stop all old consumers and start up your new API implementation. Migrating your offsets first should make this a very short outage with no data loss, just whatever the duration is of bringing down all consumers and starting up the new ones.

Comment: Thanks for the pointer to offset migration.  That might come in useful if we need to roll v10 clients back to v8.